# Add Delay to Task.WaitAll

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to run two hardware devices simultaneously at the same time and avoid any latency. In order to achieve this, I'm making use of 'tasks' in C#, however I still have a latency. Is there anyway I can put a delay between one task so that it runs 5 ms slower than the other? Here is my code:

```
    public void runtasks()
    {
        var task1 = Task.Run(() => Task1.switch(true);
        //Can I insert a delay here to make Task1 5ms slower
        var task2 = Task.Run(() => Task2.switch(false);

        Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
    }

    public void RunTasks(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    for (int i = 0, i < 1000; i++)
    {
        runtasks();
    }
```

Comment: .NET is a wrong environment for such kind of things. Better go native.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need a GUI for users to be able to access these tasks

Comment: You can certainly insert delays into code. However, doing so is almost always the wrong thing. Also, it's not clear whether you want just one delay between the two calls to `Task.Run()`, or you want the second task to actually execute more slowly (e.g. additional 5ms between each call to `runtasks()`). Also, scheduling a delay as short as 5ms on a non-real-time OS like Windows is unlikely to be very effective, as the thread scheduling is not that precise. The biggest issue is that it's not clear what "latency" you're trying to solve, nor why you think you can solve it by adding more latency.

Comment: By slower you mean that the the Task2 should wait 5ms before it starts?

Comment: Not sure if I understand the behavior. but the delay mechanism for Task is Task.Delay `Task.Delay(5).ContinueWith(t => Task1.switch());

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timer class from System.Timers, for a one off delayed action. I don't know if this is exactly what you have in mind but here is the code (I changed some parts for simplicity):

```
class Program
{
    Task task1 = null;
    Task task2 = null;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program newProgram = new Program();
        newProgram.runtasks();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public  void runTheSecondOne(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("::runTheSecondOne::");
        task2 = Task.Run(() => Method2());

        Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
    }
    public void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("::Method1::");
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("::Method2::");
    }
    public void runtasks()
    {
        task1 = Task.Run(() => Method1());
        //Can I insert a delay here to make Task1 5ms slower
        Timer actionDelayer= new Timer();
        actionDelayer.AutoReset = false;
        actionDelayer.Interval = 5;
        actionDelayer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(runTheSecondOne);
        actionDelayer.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Timers have a resolution of  ~20 ms.

Comment: I'm checking documentation but I haven't come across anything regarding 20 ms resolution. In fact there are some examples using 5 ms for a timer in this official documentation page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.interval?view=netframework-4.8   Could you give me source on it so that I can read?

Comment: Different timers in .NET have different characteristics when it comes to precision/resolution. However, all the timers involve callbacks on a thread, and the Windows thread scheduler has roughly a 50 ms granularity. Indeed, in a heavily loaded system, a timer callback might be delayed by hundreds of milliseconds, just as a result of the thread handling the callback not getting a chance to run immediately. In any case, a) the question isn't even clear enough to know what they want, and b) even if you have guessed what they want, there's no way to get 5 ms precision out of any .NET timer object